# target 'php5-mysql' is not a directory error

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, apache2, mysql, lamp

I'm trying to get LAMP up and running in VirtualBox for an assignment I have.  I've installed Ubuntu and then Apache 2 and PHP 5.  I'm using the instructions found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP.  When I enter the command shown for installing MySQL

```
install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

I get this error:

```
target 'php5-mysql' is not a directory.
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

instead of

```
install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

[install](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/install.1.html) is a different command that doesn't install software packages.